# Bootstrap formvalidation not working with the elements added using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My form contains one input box and a select box. When I clicked on the input box, a pop up will appear and based on a set of operation i will replace this input box with another input box with same name using ajax. The replaced text box now contains a value but it is not getting validated

This is my first screen
[image]

After ajax success the screen will looks like
[image]

the given code

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-10 br-de-emp-list">
                                                            <form:input path="employee" name="employee"
                                                                class="form-control" placeholder="Search Employee"
                                                                id="employeeSl" />
                                                            <form:hidden path="employeeCode" id="employeeCode" />
                                                        </div>
```

is replaced with this

```
<input type="text" name="employee" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Search Employee" id="employeeSl" value="${employeeName}" />
<input type="hidden" name="employeeCode" id="employeeCode"
    value="${employeeCode}" />
```

using ajax:

```
success : function(response) {
            $(".br-de-emp-list").html(response);
            getMySuperiors(employeeCode);
            closePopup();
        },
```

Comment: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/ use this for validation purpose

Comment: I think dynamically added elements not binding with the form. anyone help or specific about the issue..?

Comment: You mean you are adding input controls dynamically to the form

Comment: yes, $(".br-de-emp-list").html(response); this will add new input controlls.

Comment: while adding only you can add bootstrap validation class...